# Lowering of C# null conditional check

Tags: c#, nullable

This code is simply to present the question and is not meant to be good coding practice.

```
_dictionary.TryGetValue(1, out var someReferenceValue);

if (someReferenceValue?.IsWrongState())
    return;

someReferenceValue.DoSomething(); // Here Visual Studio warns of a possible NullReferenceException


if (someReferenceValue == null || someReferenceValue.IsWrongState())
    return;

someReferenceValue.DoSomething(); // Here Visual Studio knows someReferenceValue is not null
```

If I understand how the ?. is lowered, those two checks should be identical and someReferenceValue should never be null when calling DoSomething.  However, Visual Studio warns the first call to DoSomething could throw a NullReferenceException.

Is this just a Visual Studio code analyzer issue?  Or are the two checks not compiled the same?

Comment: Assuming `WrongState` returns `bool`, `if (someValue?.WrongState())` shouldn't compile at all. The `if` condition expects a `bool` expression, not `bool?`.

Comment: I don't think the first example would compile

Comment: also you _should_ check `TryGetValue`'s return value

Comment: The first example is in fact syntactically invalid. In order for it to be equivalent to the second example, it should be `someValue?.WrongState() ?? true`.

Comment: Why even use `TryGetValue` if you're going to ignore the return, which by the way the analyzer fully understands to track nullability for `someValue`? This whole code screams BO.

Comment: @Blindy: `someValue` is potentially-null no matter whether the `TryGetValue` call returned true or false

Comment: @BenVoigt How can you say that when the OP hasn't shared the exact type of `_dictionary`? If `_dictionary` is a `Dictionary<K,SomeReferenceType>` (and not `Dictionary<K,SomeReferenceType?>`) then `out var someValue` won't be `null` when `TryGetValue` returns `true`...  _unless_ the OP also ignored nullable warnings in the `.Add` method... (I wish it would throw an `ArgumentNullException` but I don't think that's possible yet?)

Comment: I also note that if `TValue` is a non-nullable reference type, but the `TryGetValue` call is followed by `if (someValue?.WrongState())` then the C# compiler will _retroactively_ consider `TValue someValue` as `TValue? someValue`.

Comment: @Dai: `someValue` could have been a value type, in which case it's never potentially-null (still equally so for both return values from `TryGetValue`) but the remainder of the code rules that out.

Comment: @Dai: Non-nullable reference types are a clever fiction.  They don't actually exist.

Comment: @BenVoigt The compiler still adds attributes to most use-sites the `?` annotation - and reflection _can_ be used to identify some (but not all) of those cases (via `NullabilityInfoContext`), thus allowing runtime decisions to `throw new ArgumentNullException` - I believe it's theoretically possible...

Comment: @Dai: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is a generic.  The generic parameters are types, not types plus some narrowing attributes.  Also, the same machine code is shared between all instantiations where no value types are involved.  Moreover, said attributes have no way to express a TryGetValue where "this out parameter is `TValue` if I return true but `TValue?`... that's could only be done with a special case in the code analysis suite.

Comment: @BenVoigt "said attributes have no way to express a TryGetValue where "this out parameter is TValue if I return true but TValue?" - that's **exactly** what `[MaybeNullWhen(false)]` does.

Comment: @Dai: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63555#issuecomment-1009323651

Comment: @BenVoigt madelson's comment reply on the 10th tho...

Comment: @Jesse - Here is a working example in SharpLab.  The lowered code appears to be the exact same, which is why I'm curious why Visual Studio warns of a NullReferenceException after the first check.  https://sharplab.io/#gist:3999cb56f45bfd3d527fc7ef4dc39de4

Comment: The code you posted above doesn't compile. The example you posted in sharplab gives two equivalent examples, so I'm not sure what your question is. `session?.IsConnected` can evaluate to `null`, and `null` is never equal to `true`.